# Number of loops in a continuous paths

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a $\Bbb R^2$-valued path $\gamma=(x(t),y(t)), \gamma :[0,1]\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ with natural parametrization, i.e. $\mid \dot{x}(t) \mid + \mid\dot{y}(t)\mid=L $, where $L$ is the length of the path under appropriate norm. Is it possible that $\gamma$ could have infinite number of loops? If yes, I would like to see an example. (Loops are for $t_1>t_2$, $\gamma(t_1)=\gamma(t_2)$. Since the loop is at natural parametrization, there cannot be a stationary point as a loop)

**My thought so far:**  A loop can only be defined on a non-singleton interval $[t_1,t_2]$ and there can only be countably many of them in the interval $[0,1]$. Thus I thought that the number of loops in a continuous path with finite length is at most countable. Even we have nested loops, i.e. in $[t_1,t_2]$ there is another loop, the number of loops in $[t_1,t_2]$ is at most countable. I could not think of a loop with an uncountable infinite number of loops. What would be the highest possible number of loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can relatively easily find a parametrisation of an infinite earring where the perimeters are $\frac{1}{2^n}$ (so that the total length is finite).

---

Edit: why do you have uncountably many loops in this case?
Represent a real number in $(0,1)$ by its binary expansion. That is "$0.$" followed by a sequence of $0$ and $1$. To each such number there corresponds a loop where you go around the $i$-th circle if and only if the $i$-th digit is $1$. Since the total length of the earring is finite, this always gives you a well-defined finite-length loop.

---

[image]

This will be smooth on $[0,1)$ only though (in the sense that this cannot be extended into a smooth loop from $S^1$ to the plane). If you want to achieve smoothness on the whole interval, there is the example of $x^n \sin(\frac1x)$ that gives you a curve like this, then you can smoothly join it to a curve that goes straight along the $x$-axis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe to my second question: Could there be uncountably many loops?

Comment: What is the notation $S^1$?

Comment: $S^1$ is a circle (also $\Bbb S^1$ sometimes).

Comment: Ok I see your point. But in this case, the number of loops would still be at most countably infinity?

Comment: It depends on how you count them. For instance, if you agree that $f$, $g$ and $f$ followed by $g$ are three different loops (eg in the first picture you can go around the large circle, or around the next one, or around both successively), then the first one already contains uncountably many loops.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great help!

Comment: Sorry, But I still don't see why the number should be uncountably many even I count the concatenation of loops as a different loop. Suppose the number of loops is countable, the concatenation for each fixed loop with all other loops is at most countable. Then if we run over all loops, we would have a countably many of countable sets which is again countable. How do I reach the uncountable infinity?

Comment: @quallenjäger I edited my answer to explain.